# This relay isn't allowed to send mail "From" me.com

Tags: icloud

We have a domain on a Virtual Private Server hosted in GoDaddy and I have set up an email that forwards to a me.com email, the email gets delivered to the me.com email but when I respond from there I get a (This relay isn't allowed to send mail "From" me.com) delivery failure message.

How can I set up any arbitrary Mail client to send as me?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. If you want to edit the ask, we might have a quick answer. Setting up a spoof of sender records to convince me.com to accept mails may be a lot of work, but configuring a specific Mail client to be able to send Mail through Apple iCloud is very doable - we just need to know some details on your setup.

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn’t allow other Mail servers to send Mail on their behalf for security reasons - only authenticated Mail clients can send. Since your VPS isn’t an Apple server, no one will accept your reply as if you were Apple sending that reply.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/what-is-icloud-mail-mm6b1a17e3/icloud

Are you able to set up your me.com account on your Mail clients or use webmail with iCloud in the VPS?

Comment: the me.com email is the receiving email, the error comes when you reply

Comment: Exactly. You can’t spoof Mail senders anymore. @Prosper you have to reply using a mail address from your VPS not the “me.com” address. If you open a support ticket with your hosting provider they should be able to explain mail flow options for you and if they can help you set up outgoing mail.